# JavaFX TableView Context Menu Item shows up when run on Java 8 until update 5 but not on later ones

Tags: java, contextmenu, tableview, javafx-8

The code below runs as its name says on Java 8 update 5 but not on later ones:

```
public class TableViewShowingOnlyAnAppendContextMenuItemIfRowIsEmptyElseDeleteIsIncluded extends Application {

private final TableView<Name> table = new TableView<>();
private final ObservableList<Name> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Name("Jacob"),
        new Name("Isabella"), new Name("Ethan"), new Name("Emma"), new Name("Michael"));

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    TableColumn<Name, String> column = new TableColumn<>("Name");
    column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
    table.getColumns().add(column);
    table.setItems(data);

    ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
    contextMenu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("append"));
    table.setContextMenu(contextMenu);

    table.setRowFactory(tableView -> {
        TableRow<Name> row = new TableRow<>();
        row.contextMenuProperty().bind(
                Bindings.when(Bindings.isNotNull(row.itemProperty()))
                        .then(showOnlyAppendContextMenuItemIfRowIsEmptyElseIncludeDelete())
                        .otherwise((ContextMenu) null));
        return row;
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(table);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

private ContextMenu showOnlyAppendContextMenuItemIfRowIsEmptyElseIncludeDelete() {

    ContextMenu rowMenu = new ContextMenu();
    ContextMenu tableMenu = table.getContextMenu();
    if (tableMenu != null)
        rowMenu.getItems().addAll(tableMenu.getItems());
    rowMenu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("delete"));
    return rowMenu;
}

public static class Name {

    private final SimpleStringProperty name;

    private Name(String name) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }
} }
```

Can help me find the error in the code? Or if there is none, is this a regression that should be submitted? As of now, all the PCs in use have 8u5.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code looks like something I may have posted a while back...

The issue is that using a `MenuItem` in multiple menus is not really supported. While this isn't explicitly stated in the Javadocs, the fact that `MenuItem` has a `getMenu()` method does imply this. The fact that it worked prior to 8u5 is really just luck...

The fix is to create new menu items that are copies of the ones in the table's context menu:

```
private ContextMenu showOnlyAppendContextMenuItemIfRowIsEmptyElseIncludeDelete() {

    ContextMenu rowMenu = new ContextMenu();
    ContextMenu tableMenu = table.getContextMenu();

    if (tableMenu != null) {
        for (MenuItem item : tableMenu.getItems()) {
            MenuItem rowItem = new MenuItem(item.getText());
            rowItem.setGraphic(item.getGraphic());
            rowItem.setOnAction(item.getOnAction());
            rowMenu.getItems().add(rowItem);
        }

    }

    rowMenu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("delete"));
    return rowMenu;
}
```

Another approach is to use ControlsFX Actions, so you can maintain a (single) list of actions for the whole table and generate menu items from them for both the table and the rows.